# Collision detection between non-uniform signed distance fields?

Tags: game-physics, raymarching

Hi folks:) this is my first question and I hope this is not a too unspecific/broad question to answer to.

I am very excited about Ray Marching (Sphere Tracing specifically) and the ability to render based on 'distance' between points and objects rather than intersections of lines and objects. The ray march algorithm is approaching the surface but a point of intersection cannot be calculated. The shape is unknown, but can be approximated by passing points into the corresponding function.

a cube represented by a non-uniform distance field

```c
float cube(vec3 p) {
  p = abs(p);
  return max(p.x, max(p.y, p.z));
}
```

By non-uniform I mean, that the result of the function is not the distance to the object, but in most cases smaller or equals. 
This way you can model bizarre structures and animations with formulas (e.g. merge/blend objects together).

Now to give this technique more value, a physics simulation is required. Ideally between arbitrary distance fields, but I think restrictions have to be made to make it quick enough for realtime applications (e.g. sphere vs arbitrary distance field)

Now my question is, if anyone likes to think about this problem, got any existing material or knows what restrictions can be made, to simplify the problem.

Thank you very much for reading and your thoughts :)